# Unable to decode audio data and get sample rate

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to get the sample rate of each chunk of audio recorded using AudioContext but when I run my current code it prints the sample rate once and then keeps printing `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data.` Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

```js
async function getSampleRate() {
  try {
    const constraints = {
      audio: {
        channelCount: 1
      }
    };
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: 'audio/webm'
    });

    // Start recording audio
    mediaRecorder.start(1000);

    // Create an AudioContext object
    const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    // Function to handle data available
    const handleDataAvailable = async(e) => {

      // Create a Blob from the received audio data
      const audioBlob = new Blob([e.data], {
        type: 'audio/webm'
      });

      // Create a URL for the Blob
      const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

      // Fetch the audio data as an ArrayBuffer
      const response = await fetch(audioURL);
      const audioArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

      // Decode the ArrayBuffer into an AudioBuffer
      const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioArrayBuffer);

      // Extract the sample rate
      const sampleRate = audioBuffer.sampleRate;

      // Log the sample rate
      console.log('Sample Rate:', sampleRate);
    };

    // Push audio chunks to buffer
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;

    // Stop recording when mediaRecorder stops
    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      console.log('Recording stopped');
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
  }
}

getSampleRate()
```

Comment: If this were my code I'd set the `onDataAvailable` handler before calling `.start()` lest I missed the first chunk of data. Also, not everry webm chunk carries metadata like sample rate.

Comment: also decodeAudioData - This method only works on complete file data, not fragments of audio file data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData

Comment: i dont know too much about webm, mediarecorder can produce fragmented mp4, but you have no control over where the keyframes are, you'd have to parse the binary, find the keyframes, then extract the sample rate, thats not too simple a task, it can be done, i recently made an extensive study on it and was beginning to track it down